# iptables "--ttl-inc" not working

Tags: networking, iptables

I get this error:

```shellsession
$ iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 224.0.0.251 -j TTL --ttl-inc 1
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): unknown option "--ttl-inc"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

However in `man iptables-extensions` I see `--ttl-inc` definition. Tried to search the web, but no luck finding answer. Please advise.

```shellsession
$ uname -a    
Linux base 6.2.0-26-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jul 10 23:39:54 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 23.04"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="23.04"
VERSION="23.04 (Lunar Lobster)"
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: @IporSircer actually I could reproduce it: running iptables as non-root

Comment: The answer is in this xkcd comic strip: https://xkcd.com/149/ . Still surprising that iptables is in the PATH (should have to be invoked as `/sbin/iptables`)

Comment: @A.B why don't you post it as an answer? it works )

Answer (score 0):

Reproducible as a non-root user with *iptables* version 1.8.7:

```shell
$ /sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 224.0.0.251 -j TTL --ttl-inc 1
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): unknown option "--ttl-inc"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

*iptables* detects a problem when attempting to use an extension and fails, but doesn't check correctly this was caused by lack of access rights for this case and display a misleading message. Using a simple `/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING` that won't use an extension gets `iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): Could not fetch rule set generation id: Permission denied (you must be root)`.

This specific "bug" is fixed in later versions (that would be available in future versions of Ubuntu):

```shell
$ /sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 224.0.0.251 -j TTL --ttl-inc 1
iptables v1.8.9 (nf_tables): Could not fetch rule set generation id: Permission denied (you must be root)
```

One is supposed to know such administration command has to be run as the root user. Morover, `iptables` is in the system commands path (`/sbin`, `/usr/sbin` ...) so should not have been found by default (OP either didn't copy/paste the full `/sbin/iptables` or `/usr/sbin/iptables` command, or changed the `PATH` environment variable). Still the `$`  prompt in the question hints at being non-root, even if that's not something to rely on.

As root user (Using `sudo`, `su` or even `unshare -Urn` if allowed), of course the command works as expected.